# how do i put border lines between cells of my confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, graphics, scikit-learn, statistics, confusion-matrix

Whenever I make a confusion matrix, I see the cells are not separated by a boundary line. I want to put a black line bordering between all cells. Can this be done?
I am using python, sklearn, mpl cursors, and matplotlib.

Comment: Please show code to demonstrate how you are currentently generating your confusion matrix. You have not specified what language you are using or how you are displaying the matrix. Very different answers if you are using Excel, Python or R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use linewidths

```
sns.heatmap(confusion_mat_df, annot=True,linewidths=2,cmap="Blues")
```

see https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html